# decoding key-value fails the parsing in swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have these Models :

```
struct City: Decodable {
    let famous: Flags
    let name: Name
}

struct Name: Decodable {
    var common , official : String
    var nativeName: [String:NativeName]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case common, official
        case nativeName = "nativeName"
    }

struct NativeName: Codable {
    let official, common: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case official, common
    }
```

Decoding command:

```
 let content = try? decoder.decode([Cities].self, from: data)
```

as soon as comment the   var nativeName: [String:NativeName] line everyThing is okay

how can I sterilize?

Comment: please post your json

Comment: Don't use `try?`, use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch` to get the error that will tell you exactly what failed, and share also the JSON. We can't guess what's wrong with your code with the given content of your question. Maybe line 3 in second file?

Comment: Your question doesn't cover the whole scenario in my opinion. And i guess you made some mistakes in building models. But I usually go to this site `https://app.quicktype.io/` and make a model from here and rename the `structures`. you can try and let me know your outcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `nativeName` key is optional

```
let nativeName: [String:NativeName]?
```

Also delete all `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {` content in your case there is no need for it at all